# Error while updating email send definition using SOAP request

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, soap, fuel-sdk, node.js

Following is my SOAP envelope

```
{ uri: 'https://webservice.s6.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx',
      method: 'POST',
      headers: 
       { 'User-Agent': 'node-fuel/1.3.1',
         'Content-Type': 'text/xml',
         SOAPAction: 'Update' },
      body: '
    <Envelope
        xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">\n  
        <Header>\n    
            <To>https://webservice.s6.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx</To>\n    
            <fueloauth
                xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
            </fueloauth>\n  
        </Header>\n  
        <Body>\n    
            <UpdateRequest
                xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">\n      
                <Options/>\n      
                <Objects xsi:type="EmailSendDefinition">\n        
                    <CustomerKey>1504XXXXXXXXX</CustomerKey>\n        
                    <EmailSubject>➡ Application required: we\'ve got the job for you - Tesco and Experian are recruiting today</EmailSubject>\n        
                    <Client>\n          
                        <ID>xxxxxxx</ID>\n        
                    </Client>\n      
                </Objects>\n    
            </UpdateRequest>\n  
        </Body>\n
    </Envelope>' }
```

I am getting following error :

> {   "StatusCode": "Error",   "StatusMessage": "Exception occurred
>   during [UpdateEmailSendDefinition] ErrorID = 497866104",
>   "OrdinalID": "0",   "ErrorCode": "9999999",   "Object": {
>       "Client": {
>         "ID": "XXXXXX"
>       },
>       "PartnerKey": "",
>       "ObjectID": "xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxxx",
>       "CustomerKey": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
>       "EmailSubject": "➡ Application required: we've got the job for you - Tesco and Experian are recruiting today"   } }

Answer (score 0):

Please check PHP & C# SDK github repo to do CRUD operations on EmailSendDefinition object. Hope it helps.

https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-PHP
https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-CSharp